# Nest quotes in HTML for IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I have some code following :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function display(obj) {
    var targetDiv = document.getElementById(obj);
    targetDiv.style.display='inline-block';
}

</script>


<input onClick="display('id')">      <!-it doesn't work in IE8->

<input onClick="display('id');">      <!-it works in IE8->

<input onClick='display("id")'>      <!-it works in IE8->
```

the original style for the target block is "display:none;", The purpose of the code above is to display the block.
I am a beginner in HTML/Js, May someone explain it to me? Many thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

All the alternatives are correct and have exactly the same effect. The semicolon has no impact here; it is just a matter of coding style whether you use it in a context like this or not. Double and single quotation marks, when used properly as here, have the same meaning.

The problem you are facing (whatever it is – you did not specify what “does not work” means) is elsewhere, in some part of the code that was not disclosed. In future, please provide, if possible, a self-contained minimal document that reproduces the issue, preferably with a jsfiddle link for quick checking.